# Can we use Material UI with Bootstrap 4

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, responsiveness

I am developing a web app in react js and i am using material-UI for components but i,m bit confuse reagrding the responsiveness of my web pages.
so i wanted to know that can i use Bootstrap 4 with material-Ui.

any help would definetely be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, Material UI components don't change anything about the layout of your page.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can, but remember that Material-UI is heavy dependencies, so it increases your app size a lot. 
You also can use some material themes for Bootstrap 4, for example: 
http://daemonite.github.io/material/
and
http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/

Comment: These examples does not use Material-UI React UI Kit components that @vikas-singh is asking for.